# Drupal SimpleNews with I18N and anonymous user

Tags: i18n-l10n, emails

I am implementing [simplenews](http://drupal.org/project/simplenews) on a new Drupal website. 
Most users, if not all, will not be connected (registered).

I eventually managed to allow anonymous user to register to the newsletter (simple permission settings).

However, is there a simple way (that is, without altering the module code) to register email of users and their current 'locale' AND only send the newsletter of a given language to those who subscribed to it.

I.E. : A french user should not get an english newsletter and vice-versa.

I already made the newsletter translatable via "Content translation".

Thank you.

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Comment: Problem still pending. Moved to some other "features" of the project in the meantime.

Comment: This is currently not possible, unless you use a different newsletter (category) for each language, as suggested in the comments. Feel free to create a feature request in the issue queue.

Comment: Im looking for a solution for this. Any luck?